# Window doesn't appear on macOS

Tags: c, sfml

I'm getting initiated to the CSFML library with macOS. But I can't display the window. The application launches well, but it goes into "does not answer" and no window is displayed...

Here is my code:

```
sfRenderWindow *new_window(void)
{
    sfRenderWindow *window;
    sfVideoMode video_mode = {1920, 1080, 32};

    window = sfRenderWindow_create(video_mode,
                                    "My Hunter",
                                    sfDefaultStyle,
                                    NULL);
    return window;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    sfRenderWindow *window = new_window();

    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        sfRenderWindow_clear(window, sfBlack);
        sfRenderWindow_display(window);
    }
    sfRenderWindow_destroy(window);
}
```

And my my.h:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.h>
#include <SFML/Window.h>
#include <SFML/System.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: In your main loop, you also need to poll for events (draw, mouse, keyboard, etc...) from the os. For reference, see e.g. here: https://epitech-2022-technical-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csfml.html#examples and merry christmas!

Comment: What I don't understand is why I would have to listen to an event to display a window?

Comment: Because the os, well windowing system sends events to your window that you should then read and (possibly) process. I would assume "not responding" gets triggered when the event queue for the window gets sufficiently large.

Comment: Well, It works, and I got the why of the how. Thanks a lot!